# Nest js gatway events are not being triggered

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, nestjs, nest

I am trying to add socket io to my nest js appliaction

Here is my gatway.ts code

```
import { MessageBody, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway } from "@nestjs/websockets";

@WebSocketGateway()
export class MyGateway{
    @SubscribeMessage('newMessage')
    onNewMessage(@MessageBody() body: any){
        console.log(body)
    }
}
```

and here is my gateway.module.ts code

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MyGateway } from "./gateway";

@Module({
    providers:[MyGateway]
})
export class GatewayModule{}
```

and here is my app.module.ts code

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { configValidationSchema } from './config/config.schema';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { typeOrmConfig } from 'db/data-source';
import {User} from './dataObjects/user.entity'
import { GroupsModule } from './groups/groups.module';
import { GatewayModule } from './gateway/gateway.module';
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    UsersModule,
    AuthModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: [`./src/config/.env.${process.env.STAGE}`],
      validationSchema: configValidationSchema,
      cache: true,
    }),
    GroupsModule,
    GatewayModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here is my main.ts code

```
import { Logger, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { TransformInterceptor } from './app-interceptors/transform.interceptor';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  const appGlobalPrefix = configService.get<string>('APP_GLOBAL_PREFIX', '');
  app.setGlobalPrefix(appGlobalPrefix);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor());
  const appPort = configService.get<number>('APP_PORT', 3000);
  await app.listen(appPort);

  const stage = process.env.STAGE;
  Logger.log(
    'App is running in "' +
      stage +
      '" stage, and it is listening at: http://localhost:' +
      appPort +
      '/' +
      appGlobalPrefix +
      '/',
  );
}
bootstrap();
```

I tried to connect to localhost:3000 via postman it returns **Error: Unexpected server response: 404** and in the logs i don't see subscription log to my event in the gateway code, but i see ** GatewayModule dependencies initialized**

Comment: Have you tried this code 
@WebSocketGateway({
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    },
    transports: ['websocket','polling'],
  })

Comment: Me too facing the same issue.